# how to change font size in this situation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website and the banner on the home page looks like when viewed as raw html

```
  <div class="alert alert-primary large" role="alert">Something</a><caption>More stuff</caption>
```

My question is how do I increase the font size. Seems simple but have changed the word after primary to large, small, etc and nothing really changes.

Pardon my lack of knowledge. Was given the task of modifying a new website and as of yet, there is no information about where the css is stored. In the previous website (DotNetNuke), it was a folder

Comment: Post your CSS please. And if you're using a framework or library with its own CSS, please update the tags on your question

Comment: @FreduahGideon The downvote arrow also is used when the OP has not shown any research effort. In other words, the OP hasn't demonstrated trying anything. In situations like this, a [mcve] is usually needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css to change the font-size of the element.
just edit your code as such

```
  <div class="alert alert-primary large" style="font-size: 50px !important;" role="alert">Something</a><caption>More stuff</caption>
```

or you could create a custom class name and add it to your class attribute

open a `<style> </style>` tag and do something like this

```
<style>
.anyNameYouWantToUseHere{
font-size:50px !important;
}`
 </style>

  <div class="alert alert-primary large anyNameYouWantToUseHere" role="alert">Something</a><caption>More stuff</caption>
```

You can change the font-size to any size you want.

It can be in pixels or percentages but not limited to these two only.
I added important because i noticed you're using bootstrap.
The `important` code  i added was to force the element to get the specified styling regardless of it's previous styling.

Again make sure the style attribute comes after the class attribute else the class styling can overwrite the current styling

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
 style="font-size:18px;"
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect for the font size t get bigger only by adding words to the class..
I see you are using Bootstrap CSS, so either use any of the alreay included classes from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/ or create your own definition of class `large` like:

```
<style>
.large{
font-size: 24px;
}
```

and put that in the  section of your HTML

#### OR

you could do this inline:

```
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="font-size: 24px;">Something</a><caption>More stuff</caption>
```

but the recommended way is to use .css file or `<style>` in the header

Answer (score 1):

Use the corresponding `h1`, `h2`, `h3`...  classes to increase font size:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="alert alert-primary large h3" role="alert">Something</a><caption>More stuff</caption>
```